# Why can't I connect to my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

I'm trying to connect to my Minecraft server for the first time but I am unable to which frustrates me greatly.
I have added the `Minecraft_Server.exe` to the Firewall as public and I checked my computer's IP address in command prompt with the `ipconfig` command. When I enter the IP and the Port in 'Direct Connect' it does not let me connect.
When I check the server log, it says: `[INFO] Disconnected /10.0.0.68:25565 Protocol Error`.
What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Do you have whitelist enabled in your server.properties?

Comment: `Minecraft_Server.exe` runs javaw, IIRC, so adding it to the Firewall does nothing. If @jski's answer doesn't help, could you post your complete server log? There might be more hints to the problem that you have overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Are you hosting the server on the same machine as you're trying to play?  You wouldn't want to connect to the IP; that won't work.

Assuming this is the case, try connecting to "127.0.0.1:25565", if 25565 is your port.  This should work fine.  You should also, if your firewall is set correctly, be allowed to connect to your computer's LAN IP (10.0.0.68:25565) from another machine on your network.  Good luck!

Comment: can also connect to `localhost` instead of dealing with numbers and dots